# nginx rewrite uri to file

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I need nginx to open files by uri like:

http://example.com/en/foo/test-bar from /var/www/example.com/en_US/_foo_test_bar

or

http://example.com/en/foo2/test2-bar from /var/www/example.com/en_US/_foo2_test2_bar

replacing all symbols except letters/numbers to underline. How should look this location, may be better would be using redirect?

```
location /en/ {
rewrite ...
}
```

I don't know best practice for such mechanism in nginx and regexp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rewrite` to recursively change the symbols until they are all changed. Assuming that the real files are under `en_US` as your example shows:

```
location /en/ {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)[^A-Za-z0-9_](.*)$ /en/$1_$2 last;
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en_US/$1 last;
}
location /en_US/ {
    root /path/to/real/files;
}
```

The first `rewrite` repeatedly matches until all of the symbols are consumed. The second `rewrite` prepares the URI to serve the real file.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.